# WordPress Content Migration & 301 Redirect Doubts

Tags: wordpress, redirect, migration

I have a blog with a free plan on WordPress for almost 5 years. Let’s say it is abc. wordpress. com
Now, I want to change my blog name to xyz. com and I want to migrate my content from WordPress to Wix without losing any data or followers.
As per my research, I need to do the following steps.

1. Buy a domain – xyz. com
2. Export content from WordPress
3. Go to Wix blogs and import content
4. Site redirect on WordPress – 301 redirect

Can anyone verify these steps and let me know if I’m on the right track or not? Please let me know if I’m missing something or messing something!
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!